# Existence of generic filters when forcing with a class of conditions.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

As the title says, suppose we have a countable transitive model of ZFC like $M$ and suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is a class partial order in $M$. My question is how can we prove that the cardinality of definable classes over $M$ is countable? Do we have to formalize logic in ZFC and use the fact that the number of formulas with free variables in $M$ is countable? If so, can you please guide me on how to do this formally? If not, is there another simpler method?
Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.

A definable class is given by a formula and a tuple of parameters (we can in fact assume it is a single parameter by the fact a tuple is in fact an object in the model). The language is countable, so there are only countably many formulas. If the model is countable, so there are only countably many tuples of objects.

In particular, there are only countably many classes.

Comment: I know but we would like to express this fact in $V$ right?

Comment: The language and the model are both countable objects in $V$.

Comment: To show this does it suffice to introduce a predicate like: $MSentence(x) \leftrightarrow Frm(x) \wedge Freevars(x) = \emptyset \wedge Const(x) \subset M$ and show that $C = \{ x: Msentence(x) \}$ is countable?

Comment: Surely you've done the construction of $L$. How did you prove that $|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ for infinite ordinals?

Comment: For that we used induction and the structure of $cl(L_\alpha)$ because it was a simple union that introduced atmost $|\alpha| . \aleph_0$ elements. But here i can't find something like this.

Comment: The definition of $L_{\alpha+1}$ is *literally* the definable classes of $L_\alpha$.

Comment: Oh... ok. Just to be clear that i understood it right we have $\text{def}(M) = cl(M \cup \{M\}$, and we are done? (By my above reasoning for $L$.)

Comment: Yes. You need to know that an element of $\operatorname{def}(M)$ is a subset of $M$ which is definable by a first-order formula with parameters from $M$, but that's about that.